# How to connect db in Typed Racket?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

According to [official docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/db/using-db.html), it's very convenient to connect postgresql by

```
(require db)
(define pgc
  (postgresql-connect #:user "example"
                      #:database "exampledb"
                      #:password "password"))
```

However, this does not work in Typed Racket (I had `(require typed/db)`):

> postgresql-connect: unbound identifier in module in:
>   postgresql-connect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right... it turns out that typed/db is only for use with sqlite3. Here's an example of some code that works for me:

```
#lang typed/racket

(require/typed
 db
 [#:opaque Connection connection?]
 [postgresql-connect
  (#:port Number #:user String #:database String #:password String
   -> Connection)]
 [query-rows
  (Connection String Any * -> (Listof (Vectorof Any)))]
 [query-list
  (Connection String Any * -> (Listof Any))])

(define conn
    (postgresql-connect #:port 13432
                        #:user db-username
                        #:database "scheduling"
                        #:password db-password))
(define rows
  (query-rows
   conn
   (~a "SELECT * FROM course_mappings")))
```

Note that I've provided types only for the functions I wanted to use. To use, e.g., `query-exec`, you'd want to provide a separate type for that.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I should provide `query-value` as `(Connection String Any * -> Any)` because in some case I have to query some `String`, while in some case I have to query some `Integer`.  But if I provide it as `Any`, I have to make every function call it has type `Any`. For example, `(: getadd (-> Integer Any))`. Actually I want this function to return `String`.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me whether you're hoping to alter the input or the output arguments of query-value. If it's the output, then a cast will definitely be required; there's no way for TR to guarantee that the value returned from the database will be of the desired type without a runtime check. To cast a value `v` to a string, just use `(cast v String)`. This will perform a runtime check, and the resulting expression will have type `String`.